# Find words in a sentence and its index position using a for loop

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

I am writing a code that prompts the user to enter a sentence which is then defined as `str1` and then is prompted to enter a word defined as `str2`.

For example:

```
Please enter a sentence: i like to code in python and code things
Thank you, you entered:  i like to code in python and code things
Please enter a word: code
```

I want to use a `for` loop to find `str2` in `str1` to print whether the word is or is not found, and if it has been found, the index position(s) of `str2`.

Currently I have this code:

```
str1Input = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
print("Thank you, you entered: ",str1Input)

str1 = str1Input.split()

str2 = input("Please enter a word: ")

if str2 in str1:
    for str2 in str1:
        print("That word was found at index position", str1.index(str2)+1)
else:
    print("Sorry that word was not found")
```

Although, the outcome appears to print whether or not the index position was found but then prints the index position of every word inside the sentence. Also if I am searching of a certain word that appears twice in that sentence, it just prints the index position of the first time the word is seen in the sentence, for example:

```
Please enter a sentence: i like to code in python and code things
Please enter a word: code
Thank you, you entered:  i like to code in python and code things


That word was found at index position: 1
That word was found at index position: 2
That word was found at index position: 3
That word was found at index position: 4
That word was found at index position: 5
That word was found at index position: 6
That word was found at index position: 7
That word was found at index position: 4
That word was found at index position: 9
```

If anyone could help me and anyone else attempting something similar to this that would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure to use comparisons in if/else statements and think about what your loop is doing.

Hope this is simple enough but effective:

**EDIT:** Add a counter rather than using ".index()". Just keeps it nice and basic:

```
str1In = "I like to code a few things and code a lot"
str2 = "code"
str1 = str1In.split()

indexCount = 0
for word in str1:
    if word == str2:
       print("Your word was found at index point",int(indexCount))
    else:
       print("Your word was not found at",int(indexCount))
    indexCount += 1
```

Comment: That's great and works, although my code still prints the index position of the word the first time it appears. Is there a way i can fix this sticking to a similar method, because your initial answer was very simple and helpful :)

Comment: My bad dude. My sloppy coding!. See the edit to the post to add a counter for the index point. (It just adds 1 to a count every-time the loop starts again. Apologies about that mistake!

Comment: Works really nicely! Thanks mate!

Comment: No worried dude glad I could help. Keep it nice and simple!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `enumerate` python built-in function:

```
for index, word in enumerate(splitted_sentence):
   if word == target_word:
       print("Index: ", index)
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate

UPD: `list.index()` method returns **the lowest** index of matching element. That's why you always get same index if your word appears twice in a sentence.

Check the docs on this as well: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional list comprehension (it's like a `for`-loop):

```
>>> str1 = 'i like to code in python and code things'
>>> str2 = 'code'

>>> indices = [idx for idx, word in enumerate(str1Input.split(), 1) if word == str2]
>>> indices
[4, 8]
```

Giving you the indices of the matches. Then you can do whatever you like with those:

```
if indices:
    for idx in indices:
        print('word found at position {}'.format(idx)
else:
    print('word not found')
```

---

Your attempt actually wasn't too bad but you did one mistake: `for str2 in str1:` this overwrites your `str2` variable which holds the string to look for! Also `index` will always give you the first index of your variable so when you did `str1.index(str2)+1` you looked for the first occurence of the currently investigated item! That's why you had `That word was found at index position: 4` two times because it only looked for the first `'code'`.

The documentation is always useful to read:

[`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Comment: How do you suggest i solve the "for loop" and the "index" function, preferably without changing my methods?

Comment: @LukeP_8 Could you clarify what you mean by "without changing my methods"?

Comment: i mean by essentially keeping my code similar by sticking around for loops etc. I don't want to have to change my code too much to correct it :)

Comment: I think in that case the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42055536/5393381) would be better, or are you required to use `list.index`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `for` loop: you assign values from `str1` to *local* variable `str1` each iteration. It's called variable shadowing.
The solution is to use different variable name in loop declaration.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a list out of str1 and find where str2 occurs in the list. Here is the code:

```
   str1 = "i like to code in python and code things"
   str2 = "code"

  the_indexes = []
  the_new_list = [str1.split(' ')]


  the_count = str1.count(str2)
  if the_count > 0:



  for i in range(len(the_new_list[0])):
       if the_new_list[0][i] == str2:
           the_indexes.append(i)

  else:
      print str2, " not found in the first sentence"

  print "The indexes are: "

  for i in the_indexes:
       print i
```